# Using a GenericRelation attribute as a unique_together

Tags: python, django, django-models, database-design

I recently learned the benefits of using GenericForeignKey and GenericRelation, so I started transitioning some of my models.ForeignKey() attributes to GenericRelation().

I'm using the boilerplate definitions inside my Product class:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    [...]
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

**Before** transitioning to GenericRelation, one of my models used unique_together:

```
class Rank(models.Model):
    pub_date = models.DateField(db_index=True)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    day_rank = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta(object):
        unique_together = ['pub_date', 'product']
```

However, when I try changing Rank's product attribute to this:

```
[...]
    product = GenericRelation('Product', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)

    class Meta(object):
            unique_together = ['pub_date', 'product']
```

I get the following error:

> 'unique_together' refers to field 'product' which is not local to
>   model 'Rank'.

Is it possible to find a workaround for this error? Why was I able to use a ForeignKey but not a GenericRelation when defining unique_together?

Comment: Why did you change the Rank model? product can still be a ForeignKey.

Comment: I want to transition to using GenericRelation. To implement this in my models I've added a GenericForeignKey to the Product model and GenericRelation to Rank.

Comment: Will the GenericForeignKey in Product point to Rank?

Comment: Besides the unique_together in Meta, I believe I implemented generic relations according to documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations